# Streaming video with PHP Html5

Tags: php, html, video, streaming, video-streaming

I have videos on my website, and I would like to display them streming with Php and html5.

I tri to follow this tutorial 
(http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial) of streaming video creation with php class.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Description of VideoStream
 *
 * @author Rana
 * @link http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial
 */
class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;
 
    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->path = $filePath;
    }
     
    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }
         
    }
     
    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);
         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
  
            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;
 
            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];
                 
                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  
         
    }
    
    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }
     
    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }
     
    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}
```

So i have two problems :

1 -  I am also trying to stream to a player but the video is taking over my whole page how do i make the video is just added to my html5 player.

2 - when I make a url http video (http://video.newsmed.fr/pdv/0616.mp4) that does not work

Thanks to help me solve this problem or suggest me other solutions php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I am also trying to stream to a player but the video is taking over my whole >page how do i make the video is just added to my html5 player.

Did you just copy the HTML example without changing a thing?
look at the HTML5 example, you will see that theres width="100%", you can change the value to your fit.

> 2 - when I make a url http video (http://video.newsmed.fr/pdv/0616.mp4) that does >not work

the URL should point to your php code, not the video file path.
for example: yourdomain.com/dir/your-php-file.php?video=0616.mp4

try to put your-php-file.php code instead of the videostream.php class on your question.

Comment: Hi jacky, i think you misunderstood him, i am also facing same issue, what he meant is that, when he enters a url with (http) in the video stream constructor the video doesn't play, how ever when the video is in the project folder, and he enters the part to that video it plays.

Comment: I have a feeling that Gist code doesn't work well. It doesn't chunk large video files. It doesn't work at all on Chrome. The published example, http://demo.codesamplez.com/html5/video, works because the video path is explicitly in the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

So here is my html

```
<a href="#" onclick="play_video(event,`<?PHP echo $video_url?>`)">
<video  style="height:100%;width:100%" controls autoplay >
                    <source src="" type="video/mp4" id='video_player'>   
                </video>
```

and then use the below jQuery

```
<script>
    var play_video;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        play_video=function(event,video_url){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("play video");
            $('#video_player').attr('src',`index.php?action=play_video&file_path=${video_url}`);
        };

    });
    </script>
```

and here is your index.php

```
<?php
include "../util/VideoStream.php";

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action === NULL) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
    if ($action === NULL) {
        $action = 'play_video';
    }
} else {
    $action = trim(strtolower($action));
}

switch ($action) {

    case 'play_video':
        $file_path = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'file_path');
        $stream = new VideoStream($file_path);
        $stream->start();
        exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert on top of class :

```
$stream = new VideoStream("file.mp4 or www//file.mp4");
$stream->start();exit;
```